# How to get image dimensions from a network url for png image in android

Tags: android, android-glide, android-bitmap, image-size

I need to grab dimensions of image (preferably without loading) from a network url given from the server. Here is the method I tried to get this.

```
public void getBitmapDimensions(String uri){
    try {
        URL uri1 = new URL(uri);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(uri1.toString()).getPath(), options);
        int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        int imageWidth = options.outWidth;

        Log.d("NewDimens1",imageWidth+","+imageHeight+","+options.inSampleSize);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The string url works perfectly when opened in a browser. But in this case, the imageHeight and imageWidth are always 0.

I have tried using Uri instead of URL as well. Same thing. Does it need to done different when url is network based and not file based?

Also, I am originally loading the image url into view using Glide library. I tried to change

```
Glide.with(this.getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(url).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(this);
```

To

```
Glide.with(this.getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(url).
            diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).
            into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                    Log.wtf("DimensionsAre",resource.getIntrinsicWidth()+","+resource.getIntrinsicHeight());
                }
            });
```

Now this does give me the image dimensions but it wrecks up my original setup for imageview provided by loading the image using `.into(this)` context.